# always returning the same value but it should not

Tags: c#

Everytime i run my code in my gui it returns the value based on how many characters i put... so if i for example use 1 character no matter which one it always return 69 and if its 2 charcters it always retun 4830 which is not what it is supposed to be... since there would be a difference in how many tries it takes based on which characters are used.

```
static void Recurse(int Lenght, int Position, string BaseString, ref int Combi, ref int Characters, ref string FindPassword)
{
    //Character libary
    char[] Match =                 
{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c',
'd','e','f','g','h','i','j' ,'k','l','m','n','o','p',
'q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A',   
'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','C','L','M','N','O','P',
'Q','R','S','T','U','V','X','Y','Z','!','?',' ','*','-               
','+','#','_',};
    int Count = 0;

    for (Count = 0; Count < Match.Length; Count++)
    {
        Combi++;
        if (Position < Lenght - 1)
        {
            Recurse(Lenght, Position + 1, BaseString + Match[Count], ref Combi, ref Characters, ref FindPassword);
        }
        if (BaseString + Match[Count] == FindPassword)
        {

        }
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Main f2 = new Main();
    f2.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
}

private void Txt_Password_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Btn_Bruteforcer_Start.Enabled = true;
}

private void Chb_Showpassword_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Chb_Showpassword.Checked)
    {
        Txt_Password.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Txt_Password.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }
}

private void Btn_Bruteforcer_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FindPassword = "";
    int Combi = 0;
    int Characters;
    FindPassword = Txt_Password.Text;

    Characters = FindPassword.Length;
    Recurse(FindPassword.Length, 0, "", ref Combi, ref Characters, ref FindPassword);
    Password_Tester DataDisplay = new Password_Tester(FindPassword, Combi, Characters);
    DataDisplay.ShowDialog();
    Console.WriteLine();            
}
```

i would like it to return the result of the attempts it have tried.. for example input = 0  would take 1 try not 69 as it displayes at the moment... i made it work earlier but for some reason i cant find the problem

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your program...

First, you should focus on the identation of your code. It's hard to debug when it's not well idented.

So, you always get the same output because you only use the number of characters as a real parameter. Notice that you don't do nothing with this if statement:

```
if (BaseString + Match[Count] == FindPassword)
{

}
```

You have to use a stop condition in that if, probably a Boolean flag confirming that you have found it already, so you should not try anymore. Also, from what I see, you're counting the number of combinations wrongly. Since you already know the number of characters in the password, you should increase the combination number only when you reach that length. Again, I'm not sure if you want to count only the "valid tries" (with same length). About your problem, I would add an extra parameter:

```
static void Recurse(int Lenght, int Position, string BaseString, ref
```

int Combi, ref int Characters, ref string FindPassword, ref Boolean hasFoundPassword)

Then you can do

```
 if (BaseString + Match[Count] == FindPassword)
 {
     hasFoundPassword = true;
 }
```

And you only have to try while you haven't found the password:

```
for (Count = 0; Count < Match.Length; Count++)
{
    if(hasFoundPassword) return;
```

Comment: Goes without saying that you must initialize the flag in the main function, with the value = false

Comment: i have now added de different types of code that you suggested and i also added ,ref hasFoundPassword into my :   Recurse(FindPassword.Length, 0, "", ref Combi, ref Characters, ref FindPassword, ref hasFoundPassword);   but it replyed with error: The name 'hasFoundPassword' does not exitst in the current context.   but i  dont know what i should put into there

Comment: You probably forgot to declare the variable somewhere in the code. You have to declare it on the main function, and state it in the function